# Toggle visibility of list item

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC 4 with Razor view engine.

I want to display a nested unordered list comprised of years as parents and months as children.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
    @foreach (var yr in Dates.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct())
    {
        <li><a href="#" class="parent">@yr</a></li>
        <ul class="child" style="display: none">
        @foreach (var mo in Dates.Where(x => x.Year == yr).Distinct())
        {
            <li id="@yr"><a href="#" class="submit-link" id="@mo.Month">@mo.ToString("MMMM")</a></li>
        }
        </ul>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have added the following script to make the ".child" (dis)appear when I click on ".parent" anchor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".parent").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("ul").find(".child").toggle("fast")
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

However it toggles ALL ".child" items in the document. How to make it toggle only the child one?

Comment: `$(this).closest("li").next(".child").toggle("fast")` <- changed it, other than that, something is wrong with the markup you're creating ?

Comment: @adeneo I tried the same thing just before you posted - nope, still toggles all of them

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is invalid: you can't have a `<ul>` element nested directly within another `<ul>`.

Your `<ul class="child">` should be within the same `<li>` element as the corresponding anchor element:

```
<div>
    <ul>
    @foreach (var yr in Dates.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct())
    {
        <li><a href="#" class="parent">@yr</a>
            <ul class="child" style="display: none">
            @foreach (var mo in Dates.Where(x => x.Year == yr).Distinct())
            {
                <li id="@yr"><a href="#" class="submit-link" id="@mo.Month">@mo.ToString("MMMM")</a></li>
            }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Then* you can do this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".parent").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".child").toggle("fast");
        // OR
        $(this).next().toggle("fast");
        return false;
    });
});
```

The way you had it, `$(this).closest("ul")` goes up to the top-level `<ul>`, so then when you use `.find(".child")` it finds all elements with that class anywhere in the top-level `<ul>`.

Comment: thanks, that was it. also added $(this).siblings("ul").toggle("fast") and it works fine!